# mysqli_query does not differentiate TRUE from FALSE

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have started studying and working PHP and MySQL a few months ago, learning a little every day, and I have an issue I could not fix, besides searching a lot. It's very simple. My code was running fine until yesterday and I don't know what I did. Below, a simplification of this part of the code where is my issue.

1. Main objective:

I need a search at a specific table (`tab_classe`). I need this query returns **only if there is or not** any row with a value in `turma` field (column) previously stored at a variable (`$turma`).

```
 // table: tab_classe (id(INT), aluno(VARCHAR), prof(VARCHAR), turma(VARCHAR))

    $turma = "A28";
    $str = "select * from tab_classe
    where turma LIKE '$turma'
    limit 1
    ";

    $qry = mysqli_query($conn,$str);

    if ($qry !== FALSE){
        echo "There is a register!";
    }else{
        echo "No registers!";
    }
```

I have tried many variation, and below the last one:

```
   if ($qry !== FALSE){
            echo "There is a register!";
    }else if ($qry !== TRUE{
            echo "No registers!";
    }
```

It doesn't matter what value I stored at variable `$turma` that my query always return `!== FALSE`, where I understand that it returns that there is a row `where turma LIKE '$turma'`, but it returns always false even storing and comparing not existing values.

Comment: Read the manual please https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php#refsect1-mysqli.query-returnvalues

Comment: Ok, thanks. That's what I needed.

Comment: *"but it returns always false"* Not always. `!== TRUE` doesn't necessarily means false

Comment: If you are only starting to learn PHP then you should learn PDO instead of mysqli. PDO is much easier and more suitable for beginners. Start here https://phpdelusions.net/pdo & https://websitebeaver.com/php-pdo-prepared-statements-to-prevent-sql-injection

Comment: Ok @Dharman, I will read about, thanks. I just would like to know why people negative questions with no feedback about this.

Comment: What do you mean no feedback? You got 3 comments.

Comment: @Dharman, sorry, I should write that in another comment, not for you. I just would like to know the reasons for a negative avaliation on my question, for not repeating this in the future. I can't learn if I don't know what is wrong. But all answers are helping me to learn about this issue and new possibilities.

Comment: Hover over the button. It says "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful'. People will rate the question based on the perceived usefulness. If the topic doesn't seem particularly useful then people will rate it negatively. You got 3 comments suggesting why this post is not very useful. This is your extended feedback, which you can learn from for the next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mysqli_query()` will return a `mysqli_result` object. It will only return `FALSE` when there's a problem with the query and you have error reporting silenced (which is the default).

Checking for the return value will not yield any useful results.

If you want to see if the query matched any rows, you must check the result. However, since you should always be using prepared statements, I will show you how to do it with PS.

```
$turma = "A28";

// We are only interested in the fact whether a single row exists
$str = "select * from tab_classe
where turma LIKE ?
limit 1";

$stmt = $conn->prepare($str);
$stmt->bind_param('s', $turma);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();

// now check the result by fetching the value
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
if($row) {
    // The query matched some records
} else {
    // The query DID NOT match anything
}
```